# Typescript mixin classes with decorators

Tags: typescript

I've been playing around with mixin classes and been having a difficulty understanding how they interact with decorators.

When I use a decorator I get a message along the lines of `Property '_tag' does not exist on type OriginalClass but it seems to work ok if I create an intermediate class. Is this the way it should be done or is there another way to do this?

```
function mix<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) {
    return class extends Base {
        _tag: string;
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
            this._tag = "";
        }
    }
}
@mix
class OriginalClass {
    constructor() {
        //do something
    }
}
const a = new OriginalClass();

// Why does this not work
a._tag = 'hi'

// But this does work
class NewClass extends mix(OriginalClass){};
b = new NewClass()
b._.tag = 'hi'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, class decorators are still unsupported in typescript.

There is an open issue you can follow here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881.

Comment: Thanks, wish I saw that issue a bit earlier - was pretty hyped about the mixin classes.